How to use public functions in other source code files in golang?
Here is my codes.
//main.go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    bc := NewBlockchain()

    bc.AddBlock("Send 1 BTC to Ivan")
    bc.AddBlock("Send 2 more BTC to Ivan")

    for _, block := range bc.blocks {
        fmt.Printf("Prev. hash: %x\n", block.PrevBlockHash)
        fmt.Printf("Data: %s\n", block.Data)
        fmt.Printf("Hash: %x\n", block.Hash)
        fmt.Println()
    }
}

and
//blockchain.go
package main

// Blockchain keeps a sequence of Blocks
type Blockchain struct {
    blocks []*Block
}

// AddBlock saves provided data as a block in the blockchain
func (bc *Blockchain) AddBlock(data string) {
    prevBlock := bc.blocks[len(bc.blocks)-1]
    newBlock := NewBlock(data, prevBlock.Hash)
    bc.blocks = append(bc.blocks, newBlock)
}

// NewBlockchain creates a new Blockchain with genesis Block
func NewBlockchain() *Blockchain {
    return &Blockchain{[]*Block{NewGenesisBlock()}}
}

Both src files are located in same directory. Evertime I execute go run main.go, ./main.go:8:8: undefined: NewBlockchain error occurs. I don't know reason why the error occurs.

the source code is located in https://github.com/Jeiwan/blockchain_go

This is the first time I handle other's golang codes and not much expereinces I have with golang. So, I ran go mod init cmds. It didn't work at all.

Don’t use filename argument for the go tool, you’re only building main.go. The official docs cover all the basics, start with How to Write Go Code. https://go.dev/doc/code

Instead of running just main.go with go run main.go try go run ./.
This will compile and run all Go files in the current directory, including main.go, blockchain.go, block.go etc.

go run main.go will only compile and run the main.go file.In that case your blockchain.go isn’t compiled which causes the error.I suggest you use go run ./.This will compile all go files in your current directory and execute the main.go file.
